# Web component in angular 6 with routing

Tags: angular, web-component

Can we create Angular WebComponent/Custom Element using angular 6 that equipped with routing modules?

I am able to create web component with atomic component just want to extend it to multiple screens using routing module.Here are few doubts as well.

1. Can a single package contains multiple web components.
2. Does Webcomponents worked well in IE11.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. An Angular application can have multiple components. 2. Web components works well enough in IE11,  if you use the webcomponentsjs polyfill. There are considerations, that you would have to be aware of, however.

Comment: What about Routing in Angular Element ? How to achieve it ?

Comment: @PushkarRathod this article appear to has the solution you're looking for:
https://medium.com/@timon.grassl/how-to-use-routing-in-angular-web-components-c6a76449cdb

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create custom elements with routing in Angular 6 by doing some changes while defining routes. It is beautifully explained [here](https://medium.com/@timon.grassl/how-to-use-routing-in-angular-web-components-c6a76449cdb).

And yes a package can contain multiple web components. It only matters in which path you are building your web components(custom elements in angular 6). We can avail the components from the path it is built.

Web components work well in IE by adding the below import statement in your pollyfills.ts file

`import '@webcomponents/custom-elements/custom-elements.min'` (make sure you have installed `@webcomponents/custom-elements` in your angular solution)

Comment: in angular doc, it seemed other polyfills are automatically added when `ng add @angular/elements`: [Use the Angular CLI to automatically set up your project with the correct polyfill: ng add @angular/elements --name=*your_project_name*.](https://angular.io/guide/elements#browser-support-for-custom-elements)